# Raspberry LED python blinking does not work

Tags: gpio, python, pi-3, rpi.gpio

I am new for raspberry, I have raspberry-3 board and I tried following Python code on it. Which I took from [here](http://www.rpiblog.com/2012/09/using-gpio-of-raspberry-pi-to-blink-led.html).

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import time  

def blink(pin):  
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)  
    time.sleep(1)  
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)  
    time.sleep(1)  
    return  

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  

GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)  

for i in range(0,50):  
    blink(12)  

GPIO.cleanup()
```

My circuit looks like this,

[image]
But this does not blink LED, What is missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you connected a LED to pin 12?

Comment: yes, its just in on state, does not blink.

Comment: You have connected it incorrectly.  A photo of the connections will help.  I assume you run the script with `python script_name.py`.

Comment: yes, i tried to upload, but image size in too large. I used the same `python my_script.py`

Comment: If it's a jpeg change the quality to 50% or so.  That makes the size much smaller but will still be fine to view.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using GPIO12 (connected to pin 32) rather than GPIO18 (connected to pin 12).

`GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)` says you will refer to GPIO by the pin they are connected to.

Either move the LED wire to pin 12 (presumably marked P18) or change to BCM numbering with `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)`.

See https://pinout.xyz/ or http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html#Type_3

Comment: I used `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` but still the same. actually it turns on soon after raspberry-pi is powered up

Comment: The connection needs to be GPIO to LED to resistor to ground.  If it doesn't work that means your circuit is wrong.  Perhaps a plan photo would help.

Comment: it was a problem with that connector, after doing direct wiring, problem was solved. I accepted your answer, because it was the first mistake I made.

Comment: Hopefully that will not put you off.  Problems like that are hard to fix as they are so unexpected.